# Gulp watch for file additions and deletions

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a Gulp task, `wire` that injects the application JavaScript into index.html.

I'd like to have another Gulp task, `watch`, that watches for changes on JavaScript files, and runs `wire` if there is **a new file added** or an **existing file removed**.

The tasks below accomplish this process:

```
gulp.task('wire', function () {
    var injectScripts = gulp.src('src/app/**/*.js');

    return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.base, 'index.html'))
        .pipe($.inject(injectScripts, {}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.base)));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    var watcher = gulp.watch(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.js'));

    watcher.on('change', function (ev) {
        if (ev.type === 'added' || ev.type === 'deleted') {
            gulp.run('wire');
        }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, it looks like this method is *deprecated*.  When running it, I get deprecation notices in the console:

> gulp.run() has been deprecated. Use task dependencies or gulp.watch
>   task triggering instead.

When I swap out `gulp.run()` with `gulp.start()` (which seems to have little to no documentation), the file changes to index.html are lagged (they take several minutes to go through, which is strange).

Obviously I could change my `watch` task to just run `wire` whenever a JavaScript file changes and not filter based on the event type, but it seems like a huge waste of unnecessary processing to run `wire` when an existing file changes:

```
gulp.watch('src/app/**/*.js', ['wire']);
```

What is the recommended Gulp strategy to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the long-running discussion of this in [this link](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/193)

```
var wire = function() {
  var injectScripts = gulp.src('src/app/**/*.js');

  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.base, 'index.html'))
      .pipe($.inject(injectScripts, {}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.base)));
};

gulp.task('wire', function () {
    wire();
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    var watcher = gulp.watch(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.js'));

    watcher.on('change', function (ev) {
        if (ev.type === 'added' || ev.type === 'deleted') {
            wire();            
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This makes sense, thanks!  I had skimmed through that thread but missed this point.